# How to change position of resize handle to the middle of DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following are the code snippet for the resize the div.

```css
.resize-x-handle-flip {
transform: rotateX(180deg);
resize: horizontal;
overflow: auto;
width: 200px;
background:lightcyan;
}
.x-text-flip-back {
transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.vertical-scroll { 
min-height:20px;  
resize:vertical;
overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize-x-handle-flip">
 <div class="x-text-flip-back">
  <div class="vertical-scroll">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.<br> dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here I want to move the resize handle position to right top to middle of the DIV.Below is the screenshot attached for the same. I want the output like into the attached screenshot.[image: ResizeHandle]

can someone take a look and update the code snippets accordingly.
Thanks

Comment: https://codepen.io/rudesoul/pen/RwrQqxb

Comment: Thanks for the sharing the codepen,But I want to update this code

Comment: I share pen to take idea, feel free to ping if you got any issue.